# How to change Option Group value (from # to text) on Access

Tags: ms-access, radio-button

On Access I have 3 radio buttons in Option Group. The option values are 1,2,3 and that what shows in the table depending on the selection.  How would I go about changing the value in the table to show A - B - C instead of 1 - 2 - 3.

Comment: Please don't add spam to your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to save alpha characters to text field in table, use code (macro or VBA). VBA example:

```
Sub OptionGroupControlName_AfterUpdate()
Me!fieldname = Choose(Me.OptionGroupControlName, "A", "B", "C")`
End Sub
```

If saving numeric values and just want to display alpha in report, use expression in textbox:
`=Choose([fieldname], "A", "B", "C")`

Or have a table for these 3 values and join to data table in query to retrieve the alpha equivalents.